# Directly query and validate in Databricks or transform to db for faster query

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, databricks, azure-databricks

we have have 10GB csv file, where reading csv file and making validation is quite difficult in normar machines and Hence we have decided to choose databricks to perform the same.

My 10GB file data, changes weekly basis. Meaning we upload every week one time 10GB data file for any changes

We get client request very frequently for validations and we have to process as soon as possbile and provide results.

Option1:

```
 1. Make Databricks cluster always run, 
 2. For every client request 
 # Run Job
 # get validation output from Databricks itself
```

Option2:

```
 1.Perform query and upload all data to database. 
  # run job (upload to DB)
  # terminate/stop cluster (since weekly one time excution). Databricks has option on-demand. 
 2. for every client request directly make query to database and perform validation.
```

what is cost and performace effective solution in my use case approach 1 or 2? or two approaches are bad use other standard methods to achive the same?

I do not have any idea on big data and databricks, If some details are required please let me know. Also I am interested to learn how actually solves problem in industry.

Answer (score 0):

If the data changes at a specific time then Trigger the validation process as JOB (specific time).

If your data is expected to arrive at any time and it has to be processed as soon as it's received then the JOB cluster needs to be running all the time.

If there is any wiggle room for any latency, then you can schedule the JOB every 'n' hr(s) this way you can save money and the data will be processed in the next 'n' hr(s).

Based on the choice you make, you can use the Databricks new COPY INTO statement, this will be read, only the new files.

Note: instead of uploading a CSV file as-is, try bzip ing it, this way you can save some money on storage and processing will be faster with less resources.

Cost effectiveness is a grey area, you need to find the sweet spot based on your usecases. (Trial and Error)